# insert Ribbon user controls WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

I have an application that uses MetroWindow.
I declare my MainWindow like this:

```
<MahApps:MetroWindow
```

And in MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
```

Now I want to integrate a ribbon menu in the application.
I create a user control for the ribbon menu, and I integrate it in a page of my application.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nine.Views.Controls.RibbonBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nine.Views.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="120.213" Width="1263.298">

    <!-- menu bar-->
    <Grid>
        <Ribbon >
            <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenu  >
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Bonjour" />
                    <RibbonSeparator />
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Exit" Command="Close" />
                </RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

            <RibbonTab Header="Home">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Clipboard">
                <RibbonButton Command="Paste" Label="Paste"
                LargeImageSource="Images/paste.png" />
                <RibbonButton Command="Cut" SmallImageSource="Images/cut.png" />
                <RibbonButton Command="Copy" SmallImageSource="Images/copy.png" />
                <RibbonButton Command="Undo" LargeImageSource="Images/undo.png" />
            </RibbonGroup>

            </RibbonTab>



        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
```

When I run the application I get an exception in the InitializeComponent() of the ribbon user control.
I think that I should change my main window to RibbonWindow :

In Mainwindow.xaml:

```
<RibbonWindow
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
```

But visual studio is telling me that class"MainWindow" cannot have multiple base classes :'MetroWindow' and 'RibbonWindow'.

In addition to that, when I delete the RibbonTab from the ribbon UC it works.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Your XAML and your code-behind have to be consistent about your window type, either `MetroWindow` or `RibbonWindow`, otherwise you get the _multiple base classes_ warning.

Comment: So how can I resolve this problem ? In my application I want to use both Ribbon and Metro. 
Could I reference the Ribbon from the page where I intergrate the Ribbon UserControl ?

Answer (score 0):

Something is still referencing MetroWindow controls. There is not enough code to tell you what though.

Make sure you are referencing the RibbonControlsLibrary. Try adding xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonCon‌​trolsLibrary" and then do

Comment: I can reference the ribbon UserControl from the page.I noticed that without  RibbonTab it works, but otherwise I get an exeption  **'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException in PresentationFramework.dll'** in the InitializeComponent() of the ribbon user control.

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the RibbonControlsLibrary.  
Try adding   xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"  

and then do <ribbon:RibbonTabs

Comment: Yes I tried this but I'm getting some problems like don't recognizing the assembly. I tried different ways but it doesn't work. I don't think that it is the solution because It recognize all the ribbons controls and the ribbon menu appears in the xaml designer.

Comment: Did you try creating main window with <ribbon:RibbonWindow  ?

Comment: This is exactely my problem. I can't do this because mainwindow could not have multiple base classes.